# Select columns from 2 joined table doctrine/symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, join, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to select two column from my tables. I have two tables and these have relationship.

First table's name is : Client ( a few column -> name and bla bla bla)

Second table's name is: Service (2 column -> id and name)

(they have a relationship like that -> Client.auth - Service.id )

And i have to select Client.name and Service.name.

I tried this code:

```
$q = $em->createQuery('SELECT  c.name as name , s.title as title FROM DefaultAppBundle:Client c INNER JOIN DefaultAppBundle:Service s');
```

I ve also try this

```
$q = $em->createQuery('SELECT  c.name as name , s.title as title FROM DefaultAppBundle:Client c INNER JOIN c.service s');
```

and also this

```
$q = $em->createQuery('SELECT  c.name as name , s.title as title FROM DefaultAppBundle:Client c INNER JOIN c.service s ON c.service=s.id');
```

But no one of the queries get me a result .. Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Can you please show how you configured your mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking in SQL instead of DQL. You will return an array of objects and its relationship will be aggregate objects.

You code should be something like that:

```
$q = $em->createQuery('SELECT  c.name as name , s.title as title FROM DefaultAppBundle:Client c INNER JOIN c.service s');
$result = $q->getScalarResult();
```

To answer more accurate you need to show your mapping like @xabbuh said.

Check about this [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html).

Comment: Thanks @Vinícius Fagundes for your unswer. Can you explain to me please what do you means by aggregate objects?

Comment: Thinking in OO [Object Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) : For instance, your entity Client has one to one Service. So you don't need to do inner joins like in sql, you already mapped the relationship.

Comment: Ok thank you so much.But in your question you kept inner join ?

Comment: Yes. A dql inner join which you just call the class aggregated.

Comment: Oh yes ! its ok now . Thanks a lot